# Not able to print the dictionary returned from view function in template

Tags: python, django

my view function returns a dictionary . I am trying to print the dictionary in my template. But nothing gets printed. It prints application/json instead of printing the values of dictionary .Can anyone help me solve this ?

```
def display(request):
if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET' :
    form = displayForm(request.POST or request.GET or None)
    val = request.POST.get('ser')
    form.fields['ser'].choices = [(val, val)]
    if form.is_valid():

        #context = RequestContext(request)
        grp = request.POST.get('grp_name')
        env1 = request.POST.get('env')
        serv = request.POST.get('ser')

        res ={} 
        res = check_expiry(request.GET,grp,env1,serv)

        print res 

        return render_to_response('certificate_expiry/display.html', {'form':form ,'res': res} )
else:
    form = UrlForm()

return render(request,'certificate_expiry/display.html',{'form':form})


 ## the html template 
 <div>
   {% for k,v in res.iteritems %}

         <li> {{ v }} </li>


  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In django template you use `.items` to access dictionary:

```
  {% for k,v in res.items %}
         <li> {{ v }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I used items also n checked . still it prints only application/json

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing `res` to the template response if `form.is_valid()` returns false. Instead you are only passing the form back to the template.

This is most likely why you aren't seeing your iteration get printed out.

You need `.items` rather than `.iteritems` in django templates.

Also, you can try changing your `render_to_response` function into a `render` function. (I prefer the latter).

```
return render(request, 'certificate_expiry/display.html', {'form':form,'res':res})
```

Comment: I have tried with .items also . But it still prints only application/json . I am getting any response only because my form is valid . if the form was invalid then even the application/json should not be printed right ? @marcusshep

Comment: if the form is invalid then you shouldn't be getting anything printed out.

Comment: I have tried with render also . Still it prints only application/json .